# Why would clicking on items in qlistview revert them to previous state after drag and drop?

Tags: pyqt4, qlistview

I've implemented drag and drop to reorder items in a list view, and all my debug output indicates that this is working properly. However, when I select an item again, it reverts back to what was there before in the view, and when it becomes unselected this change takes place in the model as well. 
Example:

```
                       List View Shows        Model shows
                         a, b, c, d             a, b, c, d
after drag and drop      b, c, d, a             b, c, d, a
clicking on first item   a, c, d, a             b, c, d, a
clicking second item     a, b, d, a             a, c, d, a
etc.
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Any suggestions why this might be happening? (code sample is difficult as this is part of a large application)

Edit: This is the best I can do for code.

Custom list view (I have a custom list view because it needs to emit a signal when items move, and indexesMoved appears to be broken):

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import traceback

class ListOrderView(QListView):

    itemMoved = pyqtSignal(int, int, QStandardItem) # Old index, new index, item 

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        try:
            super(ListOrderView, self).__init__(parent)

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setDragEnabled(True)
            self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
            self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)

            self.dragItem = None
            self.dragRow = None
        except:
            Trace2.WriteLine(str(traceback.format_exc())) #writes stuff to a log file

    def dropEvent(self, event): 
        try:
            super(ListOrderView, self).dropEvent(event) 

            self.itemMoved.emit(self.dragRow, self.row(self.dragItem), self.dragItem)
            self.dragItem = None
        except:
            Trace2.WriteLine(str(traceback.format_exc()))

    def startDrag(self, supportedActions): 
        try:
            self.dragItem = self.currentItem() 
            self.dragRow = self.row(self.dragItem) 
            super(ListOrderView, self).startDrag(Qt.MoveAction)
        except:
            Trace2.WriteLine(str(traceback.format_exc()))

    def currentItem(self):
        index = self.currentIndex()
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        return item

    def row(self, item):
        index = self.selectedIndexes()[0]
        row = index.row()
        return row
```

The gui that uses it (just a form with the custom list view, created in qt designer):

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from FormsUI.ListOrderControlUI import Ui_ListOrderControl

import traceback

class ListOrderControl(QWidget, Ui_ListOrderControl):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListOrderControl, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setSupportedDragActions(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.listOrderView.setModel(self.model) #the custom list view
        self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)

    def addItem(self, string, select=False):
        item = QStandardItem(string)
        item.setDropEnabled(False)
        self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(item)
        if select:
            self.listOrderView.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(self.model.indexFromItem(item), QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)

    def setNewItem(self, row, item):
        self.model.setItem(row, item)

    def removeRows(self, row, count):
        self.model.removeRows(row, count)

    # This is here because items are becoming drop enabled when they become unselected.
    # No idea why.
    def onDataChanged(self, topLeft, bottomRight):
        try:
            i = topLeft.row()
            while i <= bottomRight.row():
                item = self.model.item(i)
                item.setDropEnabled(False)
                i+=1
        except:
            Trace2.WriteLine(str(traceback.format_exc()))

    def printModelContents(self):
        Trace2.WriteLine("[LISTCONTROL] item order is:")
        for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            Trace2.WriteLine("\t" + str(self.model.item(i).data(Qt.DisplayRole).toString()) + " dropEnabled = " + str(self.model.item(i).isDropEnabled()))
```

Comment: Are you able to create a small sample of code to reproduce the problem? Its hard to tell without seeing how you are handling the drag and drop, and the model and view.

Comment: Apparently I've just been asleep at the keyboard. My drag and drop is fine, it's the way the custom widget interacts with the rest of the dialog that uses it that changes things. I'll post a proper answer once I figure it out completely.

Comment: While I am still taking a looking at your posted code...I was curious...how were you initially trying to connect to the normal `QListView.indexesMoved` when you determined it was broken?

Comment: I reworked your posted code into something that is not reliant on a UI file, and a bit simplified: https://gist.github.com/3874603 . Could you start from there and let me know if you are experiencing the same problem? It uses some adjustments to your drag and drop.

Comment: I have a more focused/slightly different but related question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846509/how-to-tell-where-an-item-was-dropped-in-qlistview)

Comment: @jdi In the list view file i tried `self.indexesMoved.connect(self.onIndexesMoved)`. onIndexesMoved() just had a print statement that never printed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the drag and drop was working fine. First, some background. This list view is part of a custom widget used several places inside of a large application. In this particular place, clicking on an item in the list causes some fields in the parent widget to be enabled and filled with info about that item. This is done based on the current selection in the list view. One of the fields is a line edit for the name of the item. When its contents are changed, it automatically updates its item's name. 

This means that when an item gets dragged and the selection stays behind, the line edit's contents change, updating the item now residing where the dragged item was in the view, but not in the model until later through some signal/slot voodoo. 

Ultimately, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846509/how-to-tell-where-an-item-was-dropped-in-qlistview) was the answer; get the model to emit a signal with the row where the item was dropped, and update/populate fields based on that instead of the selection model.

Comment: You should mark your answer as the correct answer for this thread